# How to get autogenerated primary key of newly inserted entity?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have an entity defined like this:

```
@Entity
data class Data(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int = 0,
    var name: String,
)
```

And I insert an instance into the database with this method:

```
@Insert
fun insert(data: Data)
```

The instance on insertion might look like this:

```
MainActivity.db.dao().insert(Data(0, "Blub"))
```

Now I would like to know the autogenerated primary key that was generated upon insertion. How can I obtain it?

Comment: Have `fun insert(data: Data): Int` (though I think it might need to be a `Long`: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With:

```
@Insert
fun insert(data: Data): Long
```

This will return the rowId. rowId is not necessarily your integer, [but it will be a primary key](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) I would think it's always the same as the auto-generated integer, but I can't find any true documentation on that.

Comment: Yes, that's an issue with sqlite. You can indeed do that, or make a GET to retrieve the latests entry... Upvoted